# How to avoid field duplication when joining two vector layers?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, duplication

I have 2 point vector layers wich differ in 2 fields while both of them have the same number of fields (10).
What I want to do is produce a new point vector layer with 12 fields.
When I join the two layers I have as a result a new vector layer which holds all fields from both attribute tables.
Ideally, I would like to join the layers and not keep the duplicates.

Comment: Are you trying to "merge" the two data sets together instead of a "join"? Joins will bring attributes from one table into another table based on a matching unique ID. Merge will combine the actual features (geometries) from both data sets into a single data set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end I had already done what you propose and it worked.